# electrical wiring with 12/2/2

Tags: wiring, receptacle

An electrician used 12/2/2 for a home run to the south side of my garage from my garage breaker panel. Not being connected to a breaker yet, can I use this wire for 6- 110 outlets and also 2-220 outlets? Also, wouldn't I need to connect the wire at the breaker box to a dual 20 amp bridged breaker?

Comment: How many spaces do you have available in your breaker box?

Comment: Also, has this homerun been run to all the boxes you want it to, or were you planning to extend power further from where the electrician ran it to?

Comment: I'm not sure what 12/2/2 is... 12/3 with ground?   But this raises an interesting question that others may know here.  Is it OK for a MWBC to sport both 120 and 240 volt outlets?   But as 3ph, Harp, or Ed will probably also suggest would be to install a sub-panel.  Unfortunately 12 ga. is undersized for feeding that.

Comment: In a shop usually 220 receptacles are Larger than 20 amp I see 30-50 amp being the norm and 12 gauge is limited to 20 amp. Was the 12-2-2 run for 3 way switches to control the lighting? This would be more common use for expensive wire. George 5 wires in 2-2 w ground black /white Then usually red and white with a red stripe and bare ground.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson https://platt.com/platt-electric-supply/NM-B-Type-12-AWG/Multiple/1222NMBGX250C/product.aspx?zpid=526460

Comment: Thanks to Ed and NoSparks.  WOW I've never heard of that wire before. Again, I'm not in the trades so my exposure is mostly from lots of amateur work.   The link provided by NoSparks seems to be to normal 12-2 w/grnd.   But I googled 12-2-2 and found it. Never knew this even existed. I learn something every day I view these questions and answers!  Awesome site.

Comment: @george Anderson if you are helped by a comment you can upvote them , I regularly upvote comments that I think will help answer questions.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson -- yes it's OK to have both 120 and 240V receptacles on a single MWBC (see a Leviton 5844-I if you don't believe me!); however, the OP's usecase isn't that since they have 12/2/2 instead of 12/3

Comment: Also, what do you want to use these 220 outlets for?